# Is it possible to append a method to a constructor/function without prototype property?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

```
function DoIHavePrototype()
{
    var a = 10;
}

CheckIt = new DoIHavePrototype();

DoIHavePrototype.prototype.GetFnName = function()
{
    return "DoIHavePrototype"
}

alert(CheckIt.GetFnName())
```

In the above code,I observe that prototype is an in-built property for the function using which we can append property/method to a function.

But if I remove the prototype keyword in the above code like the following:

```
DoIHavePrototype.GetFnName = function()
    {
        return "DoIHavePrototype"
    }
```

I don't get error in function definition but instead I get error while calling the method
alert(CheckIt.GetFnName()) as "CheckIt.GetFnName is not a function"

What does the JS interpreter assume this to be??

Comment: If you append your function straight to the class it will generate so called `static method` which you can only call from you class like in `Array.from`. So in your case you should call it using you class (not its instances) like so `DoIHavePrototype.GetFnName();`.

Comment: Worked like a charm.tnx for letting me know that it creates static method.

Comment: I've created a real answer, so if it answered your question please consider it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to invoke some function a method on an object, there are 4 ways to introduce it to the object.

The first way is what you've done in your original code, which is to assign the function to the object prototype:

```
Foo.prototype.myFunc = function () { .... }
```

Another way is to assign it to `this` within the constructor.

```
function Foo() {
  this.myFunc = function () { .... }
}
```

We can also assign it directly to the instance:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var myFunc = function () { .... }
foo.myFunc = myFunc
```

Finally, we can bind a function to the instance:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var myFunc = function () { .... }
var myFuncFoo = myFunc.bind(foo)
```

The last case is a bit special since we have a function that's not a property of the instance, but behaves like an instance method because it's invocation context is affixed to the instance.

The most common way of defining instance methods is assignment to the prototype. The `prototype` property on the constructor is what the instances inherit from, so that's where we put stuff. It's important to keep in mind that the instances inherit from the `prototype` property, not the constructor function. Assigning anything to a constructor property does not make it available as an instance property.

Assignment to `this` can sometimes be used if we want to have a method that's bound. For instance:

```
function Foo() {
  this.boundMeth = this.meth.bind(this)
  this.val = "foo"
}

Foo.prototype.meth = function () { 
  console.log(this.val)
}
```

This is useful if we want to  pass `instance.boundMeth()` as a value to another function (e.g., event handler). In JavaScript, unlike many OO languages, methods are unbound:

```
// Using Foo from the previous example

function runner(fn) {
  fn()
}
var obj = new Foo()

runner(obj.meth)  // Logs `undefined`
runner(obj.boundMeth) // Logs `foo`
```

When assigning to the constructor prototype, you can assign in bulk:

```
Foo.prototype = {
  meth1: function () { .... },
  meth2: function () { .... },
}
```

If you use ES6, you can also use the `class` keyword:

```
class Foo {
  myFunc() { .... }
}
```

This is the same as `Foo.prototype.myFunc = function () { .... }`.

Comment: I didn't understand the last statements about unbound/bound methods where you used bind method and mentioned about passing  instance.boundMeth() as a value to another function.Can you take me through it?

Comment: A bit off-topic but "invocation context" in JavaScript means that the value of `this` changes depending on *how you call the function*, not where it's defined. If you call any function using dot notation `foo.bar()`, `this` is the thing before the dot. If you call it without a dot, `this` is undefined (in strict mode) or the global object (without strict mode). The `bind()` function gives us an ability to change/fix the invocation context *regardless* of how you call the function. (more here: https://foxbunny.gitbooks.io/assimilate-js/content/this.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you append your function straight to the class it will generate so called `static method` which you can only call from you class like in `Array.from`.
 So in your case you should call it using you class (not its instances) like so `DoIHavePrototype.GetFnName();`

you can read about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done, in case if you still want to use it as instance method.

```
function DoIHavePrototype()
{
    var a = 10;

    this.GetFnName = function() {
       return "DoIHavePrototype";
    }
}

CheckIt = new DoIHavePrototype();

alert(CheckIt.GetFnName())
```